# Вопрос по учебному заданию Python, ООП

Tags: python, python-3.x, ооп, классы

Класс – учебная дисциплина. Известно наименование дисциплины, количество лекций, лабораторных занятий, наличие курсовой работы. При "сложении" наименование взять из первого аргумента, наличие курсовой из второго. Количество лабораторных результата равно максимуму лабораторных аргументов, количество лекций - минимуму.
Выдать список дисциплин, по которым предусмотрены курсовые работы с количеством лекций больше заданного значения.

```
class Discipline:
    def __init__(self, name, lecture, laboratory, course):
        self.name = name
        self.lecture = lecture
        self.laboratory = laboratory
        self.course = course
 
    def __add__(self, other):
        name = self.name 
        course = other.course
        return Discipline(name, self.lecture, self.laboratory, course)
```

Не могу понять что от меня дальше требуется в задании.
Есть подобное задание:
Класс – книга.
Для каждой книги известны **автор, название, год издания, цена**.
При **"сложении"** авторов объединить через *подчеркивание*, **название** взять из первого аргумента, **год издания** - средний арифметический годов аргументов, **цена** - максимальная цена книг.

Определить, сколько книг имеют заданный год издания с ценой, превышающей заданную.

```
class Book:
    def __init__(self, author, name, year, cost):
        self.author = author
        self.name = name
        self.year = year
        self.cost = cost
 
    def __add__(self, other):
        new_author = self.author + '_' + other.author
        new_name = self.name
        new_year = (self.year + other.year) / 2
        new_cost = max(self.cost, other.cost)
        return Book(new_author, new_name, new_year, new_cost)
 
    def get_author(self):
        return self.author
 
    def get_name(self):
        return self.name
 
    def get_year(self):
        return self.year
 
    def get_cost(self):
        return self.cost

 
class Library:
    def __init__(self, list_of_books):
        self.list_of_books = list_of_books
 
    def read(self):
        print("автор ", end='')
        author = input()
        print("название ", end='')
        name = input()
        print("год издания ", end='')
        year = int(input())
        print("цена ", end='')
        cost = int(input())
        self.list_of_books.append(Book(author, name, year, cost))
 
    def display(self):
        for i in self.list_of_books:
            print(i.get_author(), i.get_name(), i.get_year(), i.get_cost())
 
    def search_books(self):
        print("год издания ", end='')
        year = int(input())
        print("цена ", end='')
        cost = int(input())
 
        for i in self.list_of_books:
            if i.get_year() == year:
                if i.get_cost() >= cost:
                    print(i.get_author(), i.get_name(), i.get_year(), i.get_cost())
 
book1 = Book('Булгаков', 'Мастер и Маргарита', 1937, 1500)
book2 = Book('Достоевский', 'Преступление и наказание', 1866, 500)
book3 = Book('Ремарк', 'Три товарища', 1958, 333)
book4 = Book('Оруэлл', '1984', 1984, 1499)
book5 = Book('Булгаков', 'Собачье сердце', 1958, 1499)
 
library = Library([book1, book2, book3, book4, book5])
print("#ввод новой книги")
 
library.read()
print("#показать все книги")
 
library.display()
print("#поиск книги")
 
library.search_books()
```

Comment: Стоит спросить у того, кто дал это задание. Возможно, нужно определить в классе метод сложения экземпляров.

Comment: Да, думаю имеется в виду функция сложения двух экземпляров этого класса. В результате будет новый экземпляр с описанными в задании параметрами

Comment: Смотрите в классе Book метод `__add__`, вам надо реализовать в вашем классе такой же метод, но по той методике, которая у вас в задании.